# How to determine which View executed a command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a View called InformationView.xaml and this same View is re-used to display the same information from 3 different sources (each view has a different window title). Each View has their datacontext set the same instance of one ViewModel type. Within my ViewModel class, I have an ICommand property that the 'Close' button inside the View is bound to. -- Is there a way to determine who the sender was of the command? (specifically, by window title).

Here is an example:

I have a view class with the following button ("Note: each View will have a different window title / display data from a different source--but the same View is used)

```
<Button Width="75" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,5" Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
```

I have a ViewModel class with the following command

```
    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._closeCommand == null)
            {
                this._closeCommand = new RelayCommand(Command => this.OnClose());
            }     
            return _closeCommand;
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to determine which window executed the command (I will have multiple instances of the View using the same ViewModel).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to know which view invoked the Close command?

Comment: Depending on which View executed the command, a different method is going to be executed

Comment: Wouldn't you derive a new ViewModel for each behaviour and override the OnClose() method then?

Comment: Yes, so far, I think that would probably be the best approach. Overall, I wanted one instance of the same ViewModel and depending on which View executed the command, the ViewModel will call a specific method. I was thinking of having just an overall ViewModel that supported all types of Views. I was hoping there was a way inside XAML to pass a parameter over to my ViewModel.

Comment: It's possible to send data to the ViewModel with the CommandParameter property, but deriving a new ViewModel for the different behaviours you want would be the better way to go. I often reuse the same View with several different ViewModel classes deriving from the same base like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. However, you could possibly implement the `Unloaded` event. Set a breakpoint inside that event method and when you hit the breakpoint. You could check the window title property for that view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Matt Hamilton (see comments above) pushed me in the right direction on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

What about just making the `Close()` method public so that other objects can specify what the close behavior should be?

Something along the lines of this in your `InformationViewModel`:

```
public event EventHandler RequestClose;

void OnRequestClose()
{
    EventHandler handler = this.RequestClose;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then you can use it from within your other view models like this:

```
InformationViewModel.Close += CloseMethod;

public CloseMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Implement close logic here
}
```